# How to inventory a large collection of LEGO sets

Tags: inventory

I have a fairly large collection of LEGO sets, most of them still as completed models. I also have all of the instruction books organised into plastic wallets which are stored in two A4 folders.

I'm looking at creating some kind of inventory of my LEGO sets. I'm thinking an Excel spreadsheet is the way to go. I would like to include information such as original price, current value, number of pieces, e.t.c.

I'm looking to see if anyone has some kind of template I could use or a quick way to automatically pull information from a site like Brick Picker or BrickLink. And also have information like current value be automatically updated.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at [BrickPicker](https://www.brickpicker.com)'s [BrickFolio](https://www.brickpicker.com/bpms/brickfolio_dashboard.cfm) feature. It allows you to maintain a list of sets you own, including place of purchase, purchase cost and seal code, and keeps track of the current EBay value on a month-by-month basis. It also tracks CAGR (Compound Annual Growth Rate) - a measure of how well the set's value is performing over time.

[image]

Clicking on the set name gives you an overview screen with key set details such as piece count etc.

[image]

Comment: Having played around with some of the tools it does show promise. Still think I might put some time into making a custom spreadsheet later this summer.

Answer (score 3):

A custom spreadsheet solution gives you great flexibility and leaves you in control of your own data. Be sure to use a spreadsheet tool that supports the use of web images in cells (Google Spreadsheets, for instance); then you can easily use online resources to automatically show thumbnail pictures of your sets on each row (given the set number). This makes it so much easier to navigate your sheet.

In addition, you can harness the power of websites such as [Brickset](http://www.brickset.com), [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/) and [Brickpicker](http://www.brickpicker.com) to get current valuations of your "brickfolio", or enable powerful database features that let you make queries on your collection. Note that some of these support the exchange of collection data as well as batch-style import, so that you don't have to tediously enter your collection set by set.

Comment: +1 for Rebrickable and Brickset. Those sites can share data with each other, have good coverage of the existing sets, and are flexible in how you can organize your data. I use Rebrickable, it's nearly perfect for my needs.